# embedding swf files in flashdevelop and accessing the symbols/buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flashdevelop

in trying to access a button symbol in an swf file which i embedded into the mianmenu class called PlyBtn but i always get errors and im not sure if im enbedding it right or using the right code to find it within the swf file,

```
//heres my mainmenu class 
package 
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
/**
 * ...
 * @author Andrew Dean
 */
public class MainMenu extends MovieClip
{
    [Embed(source = "GameMenu.swf")]

    public var MainM:Class;

    public function MainMenu() 
    {
        var MMenu:MovieClip = new MainM() as MovieClip;
        addChild(MMenu);

    }

}

}
```

main class

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Andrew Dean
 */
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public var MMenu:MainMenu

    public function Main() 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        MMenu = new MainMenu;
        stage.addChild(MMenu);

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startgame);
    }
    public function startgame(e:Event):void
    {
        if (e.target == MMenu.PlyBtn)//problem
        {

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Are you able to produce a SWC instead of a SWF? If so, it would make things much easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Export you swf as a swc and then add it to your flash develop project as a library.
Not only will you have a better workflow, you will also get intellisense code completion for your included art classes.
In flash, just make sure that the symbols you want to use have a class name and set for export in frame 1.